# doPost servlet fail to return a valid bitmap, extra bits are added to the head of the file

Tags: java, android, servlets, bitmap

In doPost, return the bitmap.

```
            String mimeType = sc.getMimeType(filename);
            // Set content type
            resp.setContentType(mimeType);
            // Set content size
            File file = new File(filename);
            resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

            // Open the file and output streams
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                outStream.write(buf, 0, count);
            }
```

From debugger, I have checked the byte[] buf, it is the same as the file.

On the client side, it is an android apps

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(_url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(_nameValuePair));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);                                      EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(httpResponse.getEntity());
        byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpResponse.getEntity());               
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

4 extra bytes, before the BM.P, are added to the head of the file. They are -84, -19, 0, 5. But the size of the array is the same as the original bmp file. The last 4 bytes of the original file are dropped.

So, BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray always fail to decode the bytes.

How can I serve the file on the server and how should I decode it on the android client correctly?

Comment: Look at [the spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).  The first three bytes of a BMP file **must be** `BM.`.  After that there are three bytes that is the file length and yours must start with the equivalent of the letter `P`.  `decodeByteArray` claims to support the prehistoric BMP format so I feel that there is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2017.06.11:

As noted, the server side code pollutes the servlet outputstream. It is recommended to leave `resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());` out, this will make sure that at least the full content is forwarded to the client.

The best way would be to remove the excess byte sequence somehow. Lacking that, the second code fragment below will ensure that the client will work with both garbaged and clean server output. Also, it is worth to mark the client code with a `TODO`, so this tweak would call attention later.

---

I think that if you checked the output on wire, and it was correct, then the bug should be on client side. Either way, if your Android code is faulty, you could work it around. I don't know the reason for the 4 extra bytes, but you could easily patch it this way:

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 4, bytes.length-4);
```

I agree that the best way would be to know the reason, but sometimes it simply not worth. Otherwise you can play around with different BMPs, different sizes, different color depths, etc to find out what influences the content of the extra bytes.

If you want to stay on the safe side, you could look for the `BM` header:

```
int bmpOffset = 0;
while(bytes.length > bmpOffset+1 && (bytes[bmpOffset]!=0x42 || bytes[bmpOffset+1]!=0x4D))
    bmpOffset++;
}
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, bmpOffset, bytes.length-bmpOffset);
```

This should work on all devices. Also, you could check if the file looks like a BMP or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It appends 4 extra bytes to the header and chops the last 4 bytes from the original.

Comment: If it chops, you lose information, then it is worth to change to https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html instead of HttpClient. The Android Dev site also recommends this.

Comment: Is there a way to determine that the problem is not from the outputstream in the servlet? The buff from outputstream seems all encoded.

Comment: Try the URL from different browsers. If it works for all of them, you can be sure that the server side is OK. Your other option is Wireshark, where you can catch the stream byte-by-byte from the server, but it takes more time to investigate.

Comment: I have test the doPost with fiddler. Same result, 4 extra bytes are added to the header and 4 bytes are dropped from the bmp. They are AC ED 00 05, which is from serialization algorithm.

Comment: In this case I think something is polluting your servlet's `outStream` before this code. Try to remove the `AC ED 00 05` byte sequence from the output. Your file streaming code looks OK. 
The 4 bytes are chopped because you explicitly set the `content-length`, which is correct if you don't have extra garbage in the beginning of the stream. 
The best solution would be removing the 4 extra bytes somehow. If you cannot do that, you can leave the `resp.setContentLength()` out, and use my second code.

Comment: Even if the bmp file is not available, that 4 byes AC ED 00 05 will be added to the header. At least, all binary data are sent to the client without the resp.setContentLength. Good point.

Comment: @MingLeung Updated the answer. I'd be happy if you could give some feedback about the solution. BTW, if you want to catch the pollution, replace temporarily the the `outStream` object with an own object instance that throws `RuntimeException` when its `write()` method is called. This will reveal the source of the garbage.

Comment: I leave the resp.setContentLength out Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 4, bytes.length-4); It will parse the bitmap properly.

Comment: Okay, in this case I suggest to accept and/or upvote the answer. Thanks.